# does Qt-creator allow to work two different users to work on the same code file simultaneously?

Tags: qt-creator

I use Qt Creator 2.7.0 (Based on Qt 5.0.1) on Ubuntu 13.10 (x64).

I wonder if it is possible to develop a code with multi users simultaneously by installing a plug-in or a different method? If it is the case, how can I do that?